# Google apps script authorisation by admin for all users of a domain

Tags: google-apps-script, publish

I have a timesheet application for employees of my company. I am not the admin. The application is a google apps script which takes the time sheet inputs and then writes them to a  spreadsheet on my google drive. When I try to publish the app to users to run under their own login (company domain maintained by google mail), it states that "Users will be asked to authorize the script." Which means I have to give them the right to view the script. I only want them to use the url and see the pages rendered by the script. 
Can the admin of the domain authorise so that all users using the email for the company can login using the email and use the script. 
Do I need to transfer the script and the spreadsheet to someone with admin rights or can I continue to keep both on my drive and have admin authorise.
Regards

Comment: `Which means I have to give them the right to view the script.` No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which means I have to give them the right to view the script.

No, it doesn't.

> I only want them to use the url and see the pages rendered by the script.

That's what they will see.

> Can the admin of the domain authorise so that all users using the email for the company can login using the email and use the script.

No they can't because you set your webapp to run under the users login. One alternative is to create a service account which could be authorized by the domain-administrator to run domain-wide delegation of authority.

> Do I need to transfer the script and the spreadsheet to someone with admin rights or can I continue to keep both on my drive and have admin authorise.

As explained previously, there is no need to have an admin authorize to keep your script code "secret".